# Чем отличается паттерн Фабричный метод от паттерна стратегии?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Пожалуйста не определяйте никакие информация о **'GOF'**.
Я не буду сейчас здесь эмулироват ситуации (если кто захочет я могу отправить **'Application'**).

Чем реально отличаются эти два паттернa?

1. могу Фабричный метод **эмулировать** с стратегии.
2. в моем случае Фабричный метод является обертка **'simple wrapper'**.
3. когда расширять какой-то контекст (класс) тогда расширяющ Фабричный метод и оригинальный объект(класс) (представьте себе **'UML'** фабричного метода).

Посмотрите на реальном манере реализуйте это два паттерна смотреть разницу и анализируйте.

Comment: Многие паттерны похожи друг на друга реализацией. Поэтому паттерны нужно отличать по назначению. Фабричный метод делает упор на создание объектов (порождающий паттерн), стратегия же делает упор на смене алгоритма (поведенческий паттерн). Можно сказать, что это определяет точку зрения на реализацию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ я думал об этом , если мы говорим о зрении то тогда у 23 паттерна используется стратегия внимательно анализируйте .)

Comment: Поясняю попроще. Паттерн - обобщенное решение какой то задачи, назначение паттерна - задача, которую он решает. Сначала у вас появляется задача, допустим "создавать объекты" и паттерн дает вам вариант реализации. Проблема -> вариант решения, а *не наоборот*. И когда вы мне говорите " у меня фабричный метод", то я понимаю зачем вы нагородили этот огород. Отличие паттернов - в задачах, что они решают. Например, фабричный метод создает объекты, стратегия может вообще ничего не создавать. По одному названию я понимаю что вы пытались решить и каким образом.

Comment: я могу сказать что паттерн это абстрактная дорожка .). То есть можно в любом варианте реализовать. Я не использую первый раз Фабричный метод или паттерн стратегии.Здесь проблема то что в любом проблеме я могу использовать стратегии , Фабричный метод не дает мне какие выгоды .)  Вы не думайте к новичок зацепились зацепился на один паттерн и буду только его использовать..Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: вы можете что угодно сказать. Не изменится факт - у вас есть задача >>>> паттерн предлагает "общий" вариант решения этой задачи (в таком порядке). В итоге конечно код может быть похож на 100500 паттернов (их намного больше 23), но вы решаете задачу, а не "вот я тут понаписал, теперь бы понять, что я тут написал, а то я паттерны люблю".  То есть  пытаетесь перевернуть правильный порядок в иной "вот я знаю паттерн(ы), куда бы его впихнуть, ведь я хочу писать паттернами". Сам таким переболел.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ я сейчас хорошенько почитаю твои ответы . Очень спасибо что заботился.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67140/discussion-between-vitidev-and-rasul-huseynov).

Answer (score 3):

Обычно те, кто знакомится с паттернами, начинают выискивать в дизайне признаки паттернов. Также стараются писать свой код "через паттерны".

И в этом кроется фундаментальная ошибка.

Паттерны предлагают "типовое" решение задачи, то есть отвечают на вопрос "какое решение типично для такой задачи".

Результат может быть очень похожим, ведь решения состоят из тех же классов, методов, наследования, полиморфизма, делегирования....

Но это не имеет значение, потому что...

**каталог паттернов - каталог "задач и их решений", а не каталог "архитектурных конструкций"**.

А значит нет смысла искать отличия в реализации, когда отличия состоят в задачах, для **решения которых был создан** такой дизайн.

ps: как следствие, существует мудрая рекомендация воспринимать решение, что предлагает паттерн, как макет, при помощи которого решать свою задачу. И как только задача решена, то нужно остановиться и неважно насколько конечная реализация задачи соответствует академической реализации паттерна

Comment: Спасибо за ответ паттерны предложено для типовых решений (я знаю очень хорошо это). Ну я опять-таки говорю вы меня нехорошо поняли. Я ищу преимущества , если нет никаких разницы то тогда зачем надо использовать паттерны нам один паттерн достаточно. декоратор отличается от стратегии допустим. Да есть такие паттерны которые они являются сходный. Я не говорю о деталей реализации (method , class , interface , (composition , assosation) delegation .....). здесь есть минимум философский преимущества. (паттерны могут реализоваться по-разному я знаю очень хорошо это).

Comment: @RasulHuseynov Вы просто не там копаете,да и не нужно копать. 0) не нужно искать чем лучше тот или иной паттерн. Нужно смотреть насколько он решает задачу 1) все таки у паттернов есть выраженный аспект, который он решает (тот же декоратор кардинально отличается от стратегии в решаемой проблеме) 2) паттерны форматируют мозг, чтобы мозг на задачу сразу подкидывал варианты решений, а не изобретал велосипед (именно поэтому многие "открывают" паттерны, никогда о них не слышав) 3) в конечном итоге просто решаются задачи и функция паттернов исключительно коммуникативная

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пожалуйста скажите как формулировать мои мысли что мне сделать именно дальнейший ?

Comment: @RasulHuseynov У вас типичная проблема, когда вы пытаетесь найти идеальное решение и поэтому вы, узнав про паттерны, пытаетесь составить для себя ментальную таблицу преимуществ, чтобы делать "идеальный выбор" паттерна. Следующий уровень - прагматизм, когда просто пишется хороший код, а не идеальный (сложный уровень для перфекциониста :) )

Comment: @RasulHuseynov А так вам нужно понять, что каталог паттернов - каталог решений для человека, который впервые сталкивается с задачей, чтобы он не тыкался с вопросом "как", постоянно изобретая велосипеды, а имел пример хорошего решения. Опытный не нуждается в этом каталоге, потому что **уже** опытный мозг подсказывает варианты решения. И опытный прогер реализует многие паттерны и гибриды, но не помнит названия паттернов, потому что они ему не нужны. Паттерны показали "пути решения", прогер запомнил, привык к ним (перестал творить велосипеды) и на этом этапе работа каталогов паттернов выполнена.

Comment: Надеюсь я буду так формировать Очень спасибо за заботу и ответы .)